# How can i use admin application in my django framework without specifying '^admin/' keyword in url.py

Tags: django, django-admin, django-views

I have made an application in djnago and using pre made admin application of django with that.I have the following urlpatterns in my url.py file and its working fine.

when i use `http://ipaddress/admin` the admin screen comes up and i can log in that ,same i can access others url's like http://ipaddress/admin/anything. But i dont want user to show that admin keyword in my url,i just want when i request http://ipaddress then my login page appears and same for other pages without showing that admin part in weburl.How can i do that?

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
                       (r'^submit/$',views.get_xml),

                   # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
                   (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the admin accessible from `http://ipaddress`, change your admin url to

```
(r'^', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Copy and paste this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    (r'^submit/$',views.get_xml),(r'^add_question/$',views.add_question),
    (r'^update_difficulty/$',views.update_difficulty),
    (r'^delete_question/$',views.delete_question),
    (r'^update_question/$',views.update_question),
    (r'^update_mcq_question/$',views.update_mcq_question),
    (r'^update_marks/$',views.update_marks),
    (r'^wysiwyg_post/$',views.wysiwyg_post), 
)
```

---

note that the other example posted won't work:

```
(r'^$', include(admin.site.urls))
```

As it would only match the admin index.

Comment: hey yuji can you gimme solution to the question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101887/how-can-i-increase-the-width-of-filter-horizontal-widget-only-for-admin-permissio/5105889#5105889)

Comment: Yuji......if i try to access through http://ipaddress/anything   then also it opens my admin interface. I dont want it to be done  , how can i stop this thing ?

Comment: that's weird. It should throw a 404. What "admin interface" does it open?

Comment: No actually it opens up my admin login interface.........and when i submit my login details then it goes to a url http://ipaddress/anything with 404.

Comment: Oh you're right, it does. http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7849 <--- does not 404 to prevent discovering of valid admin page urls. I'm not sure what you can do about that... Override the default login template?  Hmmm. I think you should post a new question!